# Add buttons in autocomplete/typeahead widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular along with [angular-bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I need to add buttons to delete/edit autocomplete which show up.

[image]

As in the above image I need to get edit/delete buttons to delete from from main list by making a backend request.
Angular-bootstrap doesn't provide any option to do it, I added code in the ui-bootstrap.tpl.js to get this feature.

Any clean way to do this?
Do mention any components if u came across any.

Thanks.

Comment: Share / copy your code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I created this **[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjPWe/137/)** to give you an idea for your final solution.

You need to register some `event handlers` to add the controls to each item as follows:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', 'ul.dropdown-menu li', function(){
    if ($(this).find('span').length == 0) {
        // Append EDIT and DELETE controls (span tags)
        $(this).append('<span class="custom-control edit">E</span>');
        $(this).append('<span class="custom-control delete">D</span>');
    }
});
```

Handle the visibility of the `edit` and `delete` controls for the active item with this `css` code:

```
ul.dropdown-menu li.active span {
    display: block;
}
```

And finally register some other `event handlers` for `edit` and `delete` controls when they are clicked:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.edit', function(e){
    alert('EDIT: ' + $(this).closest('li').find('a').text());
});

$(document).on('click', 'span.delete', function(e){
    alert('DELETE: ' + $(this).closest('li').find('a').text());
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but we already have this jquery way of acheiving but I want it to be purely angular widget.